# jQuery reset form after close

Tags: jquery, forms

I need to clear my form after a user closes out the fancy login form.

Here is my javascript.

```
function popupCloseListener(){
    $("#fancy_login_dim_screen, #fancy_login_close_button").once("fancy-login-close-listener", function(){
        $(this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            hideLogin();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: In this case we would also need the HTML of your form to help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to reset form. You need to get hold of Form. This can be done in 2 ways:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("<ID OF YOUR FORM").reset();
```

jQuery:

```
$("#<ID OF YOUR FORM")[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, there are several ways you can do this. One way is to access the jquery object and set the text to an empty string within your click event callback:

(within your click callback)

```
$(form you want to clear).find('input').val('')
```

This is obviously if you're using input fields in your form. Hope this helps!